# Numpy: Applying a formula with elements of each row of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array called `k`. Each row represents variables  and i have the formula

How can I have a numpy array where every row (depending of the number of columns, this is just an example) has been processed by this formula?

My desired output is something like this:

or

```
[[12][12][4]]
```

Comment: Your formula and example seem to contradict each other. Where do these numbers come from? What's the logic?

Comment: @Julien the numbers are just an example, in this case [4,2,6] is a row and i need to apply a formula with that numbers (can be any numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You could use apply_along_axis.

```
import numpy as np

k = [[4, 2, 6], [5, 2, 9], [10, 3, 7]]

k = np.array(k)

def function(m):

  x = m[0]
  y = m[1]
  z = m[2]

  return ((4*z)/(x-y))

result = np.apply_along_axis(function, 1, k)

print(result)
```

Comment: `apply_along` is a waste of time for a function that can work with arrays.  It's also slower than simple iteration over rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are numpy arrays, you can use array operations to solve all of these together without needing loops:

```py
import numpy as np

k = [[4, 2, 6], [5, 2, 9], [10, 3, 7]]
k = np.array(k)

t = k.transpose()
x, y, z = t
print((4*z)/(x-y))
```

Output:

```
[12. 12.  4.]
```

Putting that in a function:

```py
def function(m):
    x, y, z = m.transpose()
    return (4*z)/(x-y)
```

And if you want it as 3 single-item arrays in an array, put this `reshape` as the last part of the function:

```py
a = (4*z)/(x-y)
print(a.reshape(3, 1))
```

Output:

```
[[12.]
 [12.]
 [ 4.]]
```

Comment: There is a way to convert that function into a recursive function? (academic purposes)

Comment: @user3161852, why do you want a recursive function?  Recursion is a form of iteration; the fast way to do iteration in `numpy` is to use the compiled methods (and operators) that work with whole array.

Comment: @user3161852 What would be "recursive" about the process you're trying? Do you mean that you want to calculate the result _again_ with the current result `[12 12 4]`? In that case, just call it twice. What are your inputs? If it's always a 3x3, then two steps reduces the result down to one number. **1.** Explain clearly what you're trying to do. **2.** Don't ask multiple different questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import numpy as np

# [(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2) ...)]
k = [[4, 2, 6], [5, 2, 9], [10, 3, 7]]

k = np.asarray(k)

x = k[:, 0]
y = k[:, 1]
z = k[:, 2]

out = np.divide(4*z, x-y)
# out = (4*z) / (x-y)
print(out)
```